# How can I join 3 tables in SQL

Tags: php

Here is the query I created :

```
$query = "SELECT address_details.company, address_details.po_box, 
                 address_details.town, letter_details.address_id, 
                 letter_details.attn, letter_details.create_date,
                 letter_details.ref_no, letter_details.refference, 
                 letter_details.letter_body, letter_details.print_date 
          FROM letter_details 
            join address_details ON address_details.id = letter_details.address_id
            join signatories ON (letter_details.id = signatories.id) 
          WHERE letter_details.id='" .$_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Comment: instead of getting output i get the query itself or a blank page.the tables are address_details,  letter_details and signatories.

Comment: You had better show us the rest of the relevant code you use to submit the query to the database and read the results back. You should also read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From a security perspective, **never** build a query by concatenating values in to it as you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. Better to prepare a query with parameters and execute the prepared query passing in your values i.e. `$._GET['id']`. I don't know PHP so I'm unable to give you an example.

Comment: okay RiggsFolly thank you i am posting the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query.

```
$query = "SELECT ad.company, ad.po_box, 
                 ad.town, ld.address_id, 
                 ld.attn, ld.create_date,
                 ld.ref_no, ld.refference, 
                 ld.letter_body, ld.print_date 
          FROM letter_details ld 
          left join address_details ad ON (ad.id = ld.address_id)
          left join signatories s ON (ld.id = s.id) 
          WHERE ld.id='" .$_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Comment: hey Ali Zia kindly it is still giving me output as the query and not the tables.so  i am using output using mysql_fetch_assoc and     ".$row['company']." for the tables.

Comment: Vote up if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should alias for better readibility,

check if you get something in $_GET[id]

```
    echo $_GET[id];
```

then assign it, (or you may set it as well, if you're using a class)

```
    $fltr = $_GET[id];
```

And, try to use LEFT JOIN ;

```
    SELECT   b.company,     b.po_box, 
             b.town,        a.address_id, 
             a.attn,        a.create_date,
             a.ref_no,      a.refference, 
             a.letter_body, a.print_date 
    FROM     letter_details AS a LEFT JOIN address_details AS b ON b.id = a.address_id
                                 LEFT JOIN signatories     AS c ON (a.id =c.id) 
    WHERE    a.id='$fltr'
```